# Dependency injection in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create simple MVC skeleton and I'm stuck with dependencies.

This is what I have now:

```
$config = new Config();
$database = new Database($config);
$uri = new Uri('article/5');
$request = new Request($uri);
$response = new Response;
$router = new Router;
$dispatcher = new Dispatcher($request, $response, $router);

$dispatcher->dispatch(); // Routing, instantiate controller, execute action, send response
```

The question is: how can any object get access to any dependency?

Some examples:

- Controller may need Config to get output formatting options.
- Mapper may need Database to perform queries.
- Any Controller / Helper needs access to Log.
- Helper may need any number of dependencies (ex.:Uri_Helper needs Router).

The only possibility I can think of is to use Registry, but this violates Law of Demeter (ask what you really need).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write [factories](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/21/where-have-all-the-singletons-gone/)(excellen article). This could be totally boring(like the article mentions) so you could use a DI-framework like for example:

- Symfony DIC: See Juraj's post.
- [PD](http://www.potstuck.com/2010/09/09/php-dependency-a-php-dependency-injection-framework/)
- [Yadif](http://code.google.com/p/yadif/)
- [Drip](http://drip.tigris.org/)(PHP4): but hasn't been updated in a while.

Also I would like to point out that Misko's blog is very interesting and has a lot of good reads on how to do testing properly. Especially the [guide to writing testable code](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/24/guide-to-writing-testable-code/) is a must read.

P.S: I think you should be writing factories, because PHP is a scripting language and you should use as little code as possible to make your site fast. That's the problem with some [PHP frameworks](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html).

Rasmus Ledorf(PHP inventor) 's quote:

> Many frameworks may look very
>   appealing at first glance because they
>   seem to reduce web application
>   development to a couple of trivial
>   steps leading to some code generation
>   and often automatic schema detection,
>   but these same shortcuts are likely to
>   be your bottlenecks as well since they
>   achieve this simplicity by sacrifizing
>   flexibility and performance. Nothing
>   is going to build your application for
>   you, no matter what it promises. You
>   are going to have to build it
>   yourself. Instead of starting by
>   fixing the mistakes in some foreign
>   framework and refactoring all the
>   things that don't apply to your
>   environment spend your time building a
>   lean and reusable pattern that fits
>   your requirements directly. In the end
>   I think you will find that your
>   homegrown small framework has saved
>   you time and aggravation and you end
>   up with a better product.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a dependency injection container like [Symfony DIC](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/). You define your objects, configuration and wiring inside the container, which than takes care of instantiation.